# SwiftUI: Can't trigger Class function in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to trigger a function from a class with a button in my view, but nothing is happening when clicking on the button.

This is for a macOS 10.15 app

Class

```
class StatusBar: ObservableObject {
    func testing(){
          print("Hello World")
    }
}
```

View

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var stat: StatusBar?

    var body: some View {
          Button {
                 stat?.testing()
            } label: {
                Text("Testing")
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `StatusBar` as an Optional and there's no code shown giving it a value. If it's `nil`, nothing will happen when you call `?.testing()` on it. If you give it a value, it will be called.

Secondly, since `StatusBar` is an `ObservableObject`, it should probably be `@StateObject` instead of `@State`.

```
class StatusBar: ObservableObject {
    func testing(){
          print("Hello World")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject var stat = StatusBar()

    var body: some View {
          Button {
                 stat.testing()
            } label: {
                Text("Testing")
             }
        }
}
```